# Copying the range and pasting it directly to a .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I need help on trying to copy a range of data from excel to a new .txt file
I have gotten to the point of creating a text file but i am stuck in trying to copy the range and pasting it to the .txt file. 
The format of the data needs to be vertical to enable another program to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

'Copy the contents of a worksheet, and save it as a new workbook as a .txt file
Sub Sheet1_Tab()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim fName As String

'References
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change as per your requirement
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add

'Copy range on original sheet
'Assuming your range is contiguous.
wsSource.UsedRange.Copy

'Save in new workbook
wbDest.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Get file name and location
fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sheet1.txt"

'Save new tab delimited file
wbDest.SaveAs fName, xlText

wbDest.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

You can also use notepad route :

Alternately The following program gets values from a range of cells on a worksheet to copy to clipboard, gets the clipboard content into a string, saves that string to a temp file and then opens `Notepad.exe` with the content of the temp file

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ThroughNotePadTxt()

    Dim rngDat As Range
    Dim strData As String
    Dim strTempFl As String

    ' copy some range values
    Set rngDat = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G20")' Change as per your requirement
    rngDat.Copy

    ' get the clipboard data
    ' magic code for is for early binding to MSForms.DataObject
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .GetFromClipBoard
        strData = .GetText
    End With

    ' write to temp file
    strTempFl = "C:\temp.txt" 'Change as per your reqirement. Directory to have permission to write the file
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ' true to overwrite existing temp file
        .CreateTextFile(strTempFl, True).Write strData
    End With

    ' open notepad with tempfile
    Shell "cmd /c ""notepad.exe """ & strTempFl & """", vbHide

End Sub
```